# Replace text added by CSS Content via Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6c9po3ts/1/

Currently the class colour writes some content after.

How can I with javascript change the text Green to Red?

I have tried using, without success:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('colour');
el.textContent = el.textContent.replace('Green', 'Red');
```

Comment: Instead, why not considering having `<span>` or some other elements inside your div that are shown/hidden when the class changes?

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg41vez0/ use this code

Comment: @Çağrı Hi, thanks for your help, but I actually wanted to change the text and not change the style (color)

Comment: @Rickin Then change color to content and write Red https://jsfiddle.net/7hg3ycpe/